# Jupyter notebook not open from command prompt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, command-prompt, windows-11

I am trying to work with Jupyter notebook on Windows 11 (64-bit).

I downloaded Anaconda3 -2023.09-0. Now I should be able to open the jupyter notebook from the command prompt by typing jupyter notebook. However I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\myusername>jupyter notebook
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\myusername\anaconda\python3.exe "C:\Users\myusername\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-script.py" notebook'
```

Comment: Please post the error as text,, no a screenshot.

Comment: Does `C:\Users\myusername\anaconda\python3.exe` exist? Can you run `C:\Users\myusername\anaconda\python3.exe` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run it like this: `python -m jupyter notebook` or `python -m notebook`